# Rhythmbox 3.3 does not display cover.jpg files with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox

Since last Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh) installation, Rhythmbox v3.3 does not display cover.jpg files in music album directories.

I have uninstalled rhythmbox, deleted config directories (rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ~/.cache/rhythmbox/ -r), then reinstalled rhythmmbox with no success.

I had no problems before running Ubuntu 15.10... (not sure which rhythmbox version was installed at that time).

I have no idea what should I do now, and suspecting a bug here.
Is anybody aware of this ?

Thanks.

Comment: My fault, "Album Art Search" was not selected... It appears to be required to have cover.jpg files displayed (I thought it was only for internet search).